# Email capturing using image tracking method

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, tracking

I'm using codeigniter framework. I used image tracking technique in e-newsletters or emailshots to track IP, Refferer URL, email id(s), etc... I'm able to track the IP, Host IP, Refferer URL but not email address!

Help me in resolving the issue. I'm mentioning below the sample code developed.

```
<img src="<?php echo $this -> config -> item('my_url'); ?>/images/logo.gif?id=<?php echo $rec['track_id'];?>&email=email" width="1" height="1" border="0" />
```

**logo.gif-->index.php file**

```
@ $db = new mysqli('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'database_name');

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {

}

if (!empty($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])) {

$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

$host = gethostbyaddr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);

$referrer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];

$date = date("Y-m-d");

$time = date("H:i:s");

$track_id = $_GET['id'];

$email = $_GET['email'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_email_opens (email_opens_id,track_id,email,ip_address,host,referrer) VALUES (null,'$track_id','$email','$ip','$host','$referrer')";

$db->query($sql);

}

header( 'Content-type: image/gif' );

echo chr(71).chr(73).chr(70).chr(56).chr(57).chr(97).

chr(1).chr(0).chr(1).chr(0).chr(128).chr(0).

chr(0).chr(0).chr(0).chr(0).chr(0).chr(0).chr(0).

chr(33).chr(249).chr(4).chr(1).chr(0).chr(0).

chr(0).chr(0).chr(44).chr(0).chr(0).chr(0).chr(0).

chr(1).chr(0).chr(1).chr(0).chr(0).chr(2).chr(2).

chr(68).chr(1).chr(0).chr(59);
```

Comment: You need to encode your email value in the query string

Comment: Thank you Mr. Singh for your reply.

We are not sending the emailers to single user, we send the mailers to bulk emails at a time using a third party tool. so i want know from which mail id the mailer is opened? Could you please brief me how the encoding method could be coded as per my requirement?

Comment: More info about encoding can be found here http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php..

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you just need to change this

```
&email=email
```

to something like this

```
&email=<?=$rec['email'];?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply..... Actually we are developing a tracking tool and based on pixel tracking we need to fetch emailid of recipent
when ever the recipent opens the email the pixel track trigers and need to fetch the emailid
this should be done dynamically
If there is any source in this way pls let us know